# Import Array with YAML in Play Framework

Tags: arrays, playframework, yaml

I want to import data with YAML. I have a model named Question

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import play.data.validation.*;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Question extends Model{

    @Required
    public String question; 
    @Required
    public String[] choices ;
    @ManyToOne
    public TestClass test;
    @Required
    public Integer trueChoice;

    public Question(TestClass test, Integer trueChoice, Choices[] choices, String question){
        this.test = test;
        choices = new Choices[4];
        this.trueChoice = trueChoice;
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

In this model i have choises array. How can i load this array with yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [YAML documentation](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html) (section 2.1) or the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), they describe how lists are used. a list is described by using the dash symbol (`-`) for each item, on a new line. Please note the indentation.

For your example, you would have something like the following:

```
choices:
  - choice1
  - choice2
  - choice3
```

Comment: I have tried that but it's not working with String[] type array. When I use ArrayList, it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Your definition does not seem to match your Array of Choices init (or Choices shoud extend String):

```
public String[] choices ;
```

Try:

```
public Choices[] choices;
```

instead?

Note: seems like "Choice" would be a better name here?